# mySQL Query over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

Help needed please! I need to grab the entry_id’s relating to cat_id of ’42’, then find all cat_id’s that are attached to the entry_id’s we have just filtered by. I then need to get the cat_group_id of them cat_id’s. See screenshots of tables below:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

E.g. entry_id 92 has cat_id 42 assigned to it. But it also has 48 & 71. It's these numbers I need to output. But only if the entry_id is in cat_id 42

Comment: What all have you tried so far?  Show the code you've tried that does not work for better results here.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not 100% on MySQL. The furthest I got was a simple Select, as well as trying to grab data from multiple tables. Nothing in the direction I needed really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand very well what you wanted, is it this?

```
select
  group_id
from
  exp_categories
inner join
  exp_category_posts
  on exp_category_posts.cat_id = exp_categories.cat_id
where
  entry_id in (select entry_id from exp_category_posts where cat_id = 42)
;
```

Note: I didn't create the tables to test it, but I think the query is ok

Comment: Because I need to filter the entries down to see if they exist in cat_id 42 first. Then if they do, find all the other cat_id's assigned to the entry_id's that return true to cat_id = 42. If theres an easier way of doing this...

Comment: Amazing. That works. I didn't need the group_id but the cat_id in the end, so I just changed 'select group_id' to 'select exp_categories.cat_id' and that worked a charm! THANKYOU